# How do I count values in pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas

I apologize if I'm not making any sense, English is not my native language and I am only one week into python and pandas.

So, I have a really long data frame of transcription factors (TF) and long a list of essential genes, and what I've done so far is determine if a gene that is regulated by a TF is an essential gene or not. Like this:

```
In:
df2 = regulon.copy()
lista_genes = (genes['Esenciales'].values.tolist())
df2['Esencialidad'] = (pd.DataFrame(regulon['Target'].isin(lista_genes)))
df2[['Esencialidad']] = df2[['Esencialidad']].astype(str)
df2.ix[df2.Esencialidad == 'True' , 'Esencialidad'] = 'Esencial'
df2.ix[df2.Esencialidad == 'False' , 'Esencialidad'] = 'No esencial'
df2.to_excel("salida2.xlsx", index = False)
df2
Out:
    TF    Target    Regulation  Score   Esencialidad
0   AccB    accB          -     null    Esencial
1   AccB    accC          -     null    Esencial
2   AcrR    acrA          -     Weak    No esencial
3   AcrR    acrB          -     Weak    No esencial
4   AcrR    acrR          -     Weak    No esencial
5   AcrR    marA          -     Strong  No esencial
6   AcrR    marB          -     Strong  No esencial
7   AcrR    marR          -     Strong  No esencial
8   AcrR    micF          -     Weak    No esencial
9   AcrR    soxR          -     Strong  No esencial
10  AcrR    soxS          -     Strong  No esencial
11  Ada     alkB          -     Strong  No esencial
12  Ada     alkB          +     Strong  No esencial
```

Next thing I did, was determine how many genes were being regulated by a TF. Like this:

```
In: 
genes_regulados = regulon['TF'].value_counts()
TF = pd.DataFrame(genes_regulados)
TF.reset_index(inplace=True)
TF.rename(columns={'index': 'TF', 'TF': 'Genes_regulados'}, inplace=True)
TF = TF.sort_values('TF').reset_index(drop=True)
TF['Esenciales'] = (pd.DataFrame(regulon['Target'].isin(lista_genes)))
TF
Out:

    TF  Genes_Regulados
0   AccB    2
1   AcrR    9
2   Ada     6
3   AdiY    8
4   AgaR    11
5   AidB    1
6   AlaS    1
7   AllR    9
```

What I want to do now, is determine in a new column how many of those regulated genes for that given TF are essential and how many are not essential in another column.

I need your help. I'm stuck and I have no idea of how to do this.

The output I'm looking for is something like this:

```
TF  Genes Regulados Esenciales  No Esenciales
AcrR         4         0           4           
Ada          6         0           6          
AdiY         8         0           8             
AgaR        11         0          11          
AidB         1         0           1    
AlaS         1         1           0    
AllR         9         0           9    
AllS         3         0           3    
AlsR         6         0           6    
AppY        10         0          10    
AraC        19         6          13
```

**Update**

Thanks to JBr I got it just how I needed. Now I'm wondering if there's a way to make it more complex and get how many essential genes have a positive regulation and how many essential genes have a negative regulation for that given TF and.

The output I'm looking for is something like this:

```
TF  Genes_regulados Esenciales  No Esenciales Esenciales_positivos Esenciales_negativos
AcrR         4         0           4                   0                   0
Ada          6         0           6                   0                   0
AdiY         8         0           8                   0                   0
AgaR        11         0          11                   0                   0
AidB         1         0           1                   0                   0
AlaS         1         1           0                   0                   1
AllR         9         0           9                   0                   0
AllS         3         0           3                   0                   0
AlsR         6         0           6                   0                   0
AppY        10         0          10                   0                   0
AraC        19         6          13                   4                   2
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can undelete your question or better cretae new - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38209757/how-can-i-sum-values-from-df1-that-belong-to-another-value-in-df2. You get downvote (not me), because there was no your code and no desired output. Btw, I think I have solution for you now, but I need compare it with your desired output..

Comment: Also you can explain more if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apply` is your friend here

```
def count_tfs_essential(tf_val, df2, esencial_val):
    '''returns count of rows in df2 having specific tf_val and esencial_val'''
    df2_con_tf_val = df2[(df2["TF"] == tf_val)]
    df2_con_tf_val_y_essencial = df2_con_tf_val[df2_con_tf_val["Esencialidad"] == esencial_val]

    count = len(df2_con_tf_val_y_essencial.index)

    return count

TF["Esenciales"] = TF["TF"].apply(lambda tf_val: count_tfs_essential (tf_val, df2, "Esencial"))
TF["No Esenciales"] = TF["TF"].apply(lambda tf_val: count_tfs_essential (tf_val, df2, "No esencial"))
```

*** desired df: ***

```
     TF  Genes_Regulados  Esenciales  No Esenciales
0  AccB                2           2              0
1  AcrR                9           0              9
2   Ada                6           0              2
3  AdiY                8           0              0
4  AgaR               11           0              0
5  AidB                1           0              0
6  Alas                1           0              0
7  AllR                9           0              0
```

Comment: This works like a charm!! Just what I was looking for. Although I'm not understanding how this works. I'm very new to python and pandas.
Can you please explain me what is this code doing?
Thanks ;)

Comment: great! glad it works. which part in particular do you not understand? try printing out the intermediate steps and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks JBr!! I had to read a lot to better understand how lambda, def and return works. Now I'm wondering if its possible to make it more complex and find how many essential genes have a positive regulation and how many essential genes have a negative regulation for that given TF. Also, can you point me to a good book or guide to better learn python?

Comment: pandas documentation is good. post the problem w/ desired df as new problem and I'll try to take a look

Comment: Ok. I just updated my question. Thank you very much! Meanwhile I'll try to figure it out myself

Comment: post as new problem in stack overflow; i already resolved this one

Comment: Ok, I just posted it. Can't figure it out just yet. Thanks